# Django TemplateDoesNotExist {% extends base.html %} - where should template be?

Tags: python, html, django, django-templates, extends

I'm starting a very simple Django app but having trouble with extending an html file.

I have `base.html` and `index.html` both within `my_site/my_app/templates/my_app`.

i.e. 
`my_site/my_app/templates/my_app/base.html` and `my_site/my_app/templates/my_app/index.html`.

Within the `index.html` file I have `{% extends 'base.html' %}`.

My `settings.py` file has

```
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

But when I visit my index view at `http://127.0.0.1:8000/index/`:

```
def index(request):
    return render(request, 'my_app/index.html')
```

I get the following error:

```
TemplateDoesNotExist at /index/
base.html
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/index/
Django Version: 1.10.3
Exception Type: TemplateDoesNotExist
Exception Value: base.html
```

Do I have the `base.html` file saved in the wrong place or is it something else? I have not been able to solve this.

Comment: How is `BASE_DIR` defined?

Comment: Forgot to add that, now included above.
`BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))` and settings.py is saved in `my_site/my_site`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be in my_site/my_app/templates or my_site/templates.

Comment: I have tried moving it to my_site/my_app/templates but I then get a `NoReverseMatch at /index/` error:
`Reverse for 'index' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 0 pattern(s) tried: []`

Comment: Well, that is a completely separate problem, which has nothing to do with your template not being found.

Comment: Thanks - you're right. I've also fixed that now so everything is working. You're answer fixed what I was asking - the template is now being found.